# How to create an HTTP GET request with a form

Tags: http

How do I send an HTTP GET request without a form? This request is performed on a web page.

For more details on what I'm trying to accomplish and why, see my question here: [http get/post request and google geolocation api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745217/http-get-post-request-and-google-geolocation-api)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish might help to refine this question.

Comment: please see my other question found here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745217/http-get-post-request-and-google-geolocation-api

Answer (score 8):

Any link is a GET request, so, just make a link, add the extra info at the end, done.

http://someurl.net/somelink?value1=avalue&value2=anothervalue

Answer (score 2):

A normal hyperlink does a GET request when the user clicks on it.  Loading an image is also a GET request, as are most of the other ways of embedding things in a page.  If you're trying to do it via JavaScript, you can use an XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax and jQuery's [get](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get) method:

```
$.get("someURL.php?variables=true");
```

Note, that you will only be able to make requests to the same domain OR the target domain must return [JSON formatted results](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback).

Answer (score 1):

In plain HTML you can do that e.g. requesting an image:

```
<img src="http://example.com/?bla=bla">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
< a href="www.google.com">google</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with altCognito points out using jquery but I'd rather use

```
$.get("someurl.php", { variable: value });
```

I like this way better because it allows me to send objects instead of concatenate strings.
you can see a couple of samples [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype)